# Multiple terminals in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script, but I need multiple tabs in it or terminal.
Is it possible to use that in a bash script. I need it, because I use a few commands 
that need to keep running.

Thank you all and sorry for my English!

Comment: do you mean you need to run multiple processes?  you can use fork...

Comment: Are you familiar with job control, `&`, `^Z`, `fg`, etc.?

Comment: as ruakh stated, just apppend a `&` after a command to send it to the background

Answer (score 1):

To run a process in the background add `&` at the end. For example, this runs `ls` in the background and uses `tail` to monitor the file that's being written to in the foreground.

```
ls -lR / > /tmp/ls.out &
tail -f /tmp/ls.out
```

If at any point you want to wait until the background processes are finished before continuing—perhaps at the end of your script before it exits—use a bare `wait` command:

```
wait
```